# Android GridView adding vertical spacing

Tags: android, android-gridview

I am positioning a number of images with the same width and height in a 2-column grid view.  I want the vertical spacing to be an even 20dp, but extra space is being added.

**EDIT:** It seems the vertical space is caused by my square images being to big to fit.  They are too wide to fit into the column, so Android scales them down.  The extra vertical space shows how high the images would have been if not scaled down.  It seems when the images are automatically scaled down, the vertical dimension of the ImageView in the grid remains the same, adding the white space.

Replacing them with smaller images makes the problem go away.  Still, is there a way to make this layout work correctly, even with oversized images?

[image: rendered screen]

Here is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    tools:context=".TargetCollectionActivity" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Start Over"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/start_over_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <GridView  
        android:id="@+id/sh_grid_view"
        android:layout_above="@+id/start_over_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="20dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the Adapter that creates the views:

```
private class TargetImageCollectionAdapter extends  BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    public TargetImageCollectionAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }        
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return application.getHunt().getTargetList().size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return application.getHunt().getTargetList().get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TargetItem target = application.getHunt().getTargetList().get(position);
        // This method returns an ImageView constructed around a BitMap loaded
        // from the Android filesystem
        ImageView view application.getRemoteAssetCache().getImageByName("target"+target.getId());
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Show the `getView` method of your adapter as well as the xml for the grid items (if any)

Comment: You need to set the "`android:adjustViewBounds`" attribute to `true` in your `ImageView`.

Comment: added adapter code.  There is no XML for the grid items.  They are an ImageView wrapper around a Bitmap loaded from the android filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the vertical space is caused by my square images being to big to fit. They are too wide to fit into the column, so Android scales them down. The extra vertical space shows how high the images would have been if not scaled down. It seems when the images are automatically scaled down, the vertical dimension of the ImageView in the grid remains the same, adding the white space.